# How to use an already built html template for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, html

I have already designed about 3 templates I wanted to make use of, but after learning rails I want to use one of them for a web application. How do i use a HTML template for a rails application?

Am asking because rails seems different due to the MVC format. So i don't know how am going to go about placing the right files in the right location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) guide should help you get started.

Basically, you separate the main structure (header, footer) from the template and put it in the `view/layout/application.html.erb`. The structure is usually similar to this:

```
html
  head
  body
    #header

    #content
      <%= yield %>

    #footer
```

Every controller by default uses it's own folder for view files. So views for `articles` controller should be located under `view/articles` folder. And every action uses it's html file.

`yield` inserts the current action's view file into the layout. For example, if you go to `/articles/1` it will load `view/article/show.html.erb`

With rails 3.0.x you put assets like stylesheets, images and JS under `public` folder. 3.1 uses `app/assets/` folder.

**updated**

Yes, you have a base layout which is the same on every page and a section that changes on every page. But of course you can use different layouts if you need to. Or you can reuse the same view file for different actions.

If you use paths relative to the root (e.g. '/stylesheets/style.css') then you don't need to change the reference for every page. Rails has some nice helpers:

```
stylesheet_include_tag 'stylesheet_name'
javascript_include_tag 'script_name'
```

You can pass several filenames, or add some options that you can find in the documentation. I get my stylesheets complied into one application.css file but if you want to keep them separate and load only when they're really needed, you can use `yield` combined with `content_for`. There's more info on that in the link I provided.

Comment: so is it something like, you just have one page but the body always changes depending on what link was clicked? Also, does that mean that i have to change the reference to my javascript/css files as the location is changing?

Comment: Tanks a lot. Am a newbie in ruby so its been like hell understanding the layout... Am still looking for a web application online tho thats open source so I can go through it(actual code) and see how its done. Thanks a lot

Comment: You might wanna check out the railstutorial.org. It's a free book which describes development of a twitter-like application. The code is available here: https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app. Also, there are sources of railscasts.com: https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts